# How to join multiple matrices (or reshape) for a neural network

Tags: python, pandas, reshape

I have dataframe where each row is an np.array of size (3, 6, 6).

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/BvTsO.png)

I need to use this data as input for a neural network that takes one large matrix as input (350, 3, 6, 6). I can’t use reshape (cannot reshape array of size 350 into shape (350,3,6,6)). How can this be fixed?

Comment: *not 3 dim but 4

Comment: Have you tried just doing: `df.to_numpy()`? I feel like that should be what you need